# Logic error executing java if/else statement

Tags: java

When the code executes it:

A. Does not allow you to input the String for employeeID,
B. Bypasses the If/Else statement completely.

Code is:

```
    double salary = 0.0;
String employeeID;



System.out.println("\nWhich Employee would you like to see Gross Earning's of? (A, B, C, or ALL)?");
employeeID = input.nextLine();

//if else commnnad to chose which employee details required

if (employeeID == "A")
    {
    if (employeeA.getHours() > 40)
        {
        salary = (employeeA.getRate()*40) + employeeA.getOverTimeRate() * (employeeA.getHours() - 40);
        }
    else
        {
        salary = employeeA.getRate()*40;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("You have chosen Employee: %s\nHours Worked: %.2f\nNormal Rate: %.2f\nOver Time Rate: %.2f\nGross Salary: %.2f\n", employeeID, employeeA.getHours(), employeeA.getRate(), employeeA.getOverTimeRate(), salary);
```

When executed it looks like this:

Which Employee would you like to see Gross Earning's of? (A, B, C, or ALL)?
You have chosen Employee: 
Hours Worked: 1.00
Normal Rate: 1.00
Over Time Rate: 1.00
Gross Salary: 0.00

I think I have done something wrong with the IF/Else statement as it doesn't seem to execute this code at all.

Thanks
Ciaran

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
if (employeeID == "A")
```

by

```
if ("A".equals(employeeID))
```

To compare strings always use `equals(.)`. `==` compares the references.

Comment: Thanks changed that. However the statement that allows the user to input a employee ID (A, B, C, or ALL) dosen't seem to execute. The output apperas but then the program just continues to execute and therefore the if loop is returning false everytime: code: System.out.println("\nWhich Employee would you like to see Gross Earning's of? (A, B, C, or ALL)?");
employeeID = input.nextLine().

Comment: You should debug, what `employeeID` actual is while your program is running. Use a debugger or simply print it to the console `System.println(">>"+employeeID+"<<");`

Comment: Thanks.Yep printing employeeID returns as blank: System.out.println(">>"+employeeID+">>"); Output: ">>>>" so it seems the string has no value, not surprising as when code executes it dosent allow input to assign a value to employeeID, confused

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `=` with `equals`. You cannot compare string via the `=` sign

Comment: I'd amend that to "you *should* not compare strings" since you *can*, and occasionally you might even *want* to--but almost never.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The emoloyeeID = input.nextLine(); was assigning the return character left over from the nextDouble methods.

Putting a 'input.nextLine(); " after the nextDoubke method seems to of solved it.

Ta for the feedback